# int does not contain definition for value

Tags: c#

I am using Visual Studio C# this error has come up on my code and I don't know how to resolve:

> 'int' does not contain a definition for 'Value' and no extension method 'Value' accepting a first argument of type 'int' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

The Invalid code is

```
int Mod = randomizer.Next(2, 11);
int sum2 = randomizer.Next(2, 11);
modend = Mod * sum2;
ModLeft.Text = dividend.ToString();
ModRight.Text = divisor.ToString();
sum2.Value = 0;
```

Comment: Why you use `sum2.Value = 0;`, you can use `sum2 = 0;`

Comment: Only nullable type `int?` has `Value` property

Comment: @Rudis and it has not a `setter` method too.

Comment: This can happen if you change your nullable int to be non-nullable.

Comment: I once faced the same problem by using the `dynamic` type as a function parameter and then inside the function I used `.Value` when I was passing a nullable variable, however, if I pass a not-nullable variable the code compiles however it produces the error at runtime because dynamic type does not validate properties until the code is running.

Answer (score 8):

`sum2` is an `int` which has no `Value` property. That's all.

You can assign it directly:

```
sum2 = 0;
```

Answer (score 5):

Change this

```
sum2.Value = 0;
```

to this

```
sum2 = 0;
```

since `int` doesn't have a property named `Value`.

Answer (score 2):

Sum2 is an int and cannot be null as it is a value type.

If it's ever possible for your value to be null, which it's not in your current example, you should use a nullable type which has the 'Value' property.

Answer (score 0):

Just change in your codes to

```
    int Mod = randomizer.Next(2, 11);
    int sum2 = randomizer.Next(2, 11);
    modend = Mod * sum2;
    ModLeft.Text = dividend.ToString();
    ModRight.Text = divisor.ToString();
    sum2= 0;
```

as `sum2.value=0;`  is not the right way to assign values to a integer.

Answer (score 0):

As a curiosity, every value-type has some fields. Even `Int32`. It is called `m_value`, its type is `int` and it's not public. There's some compiler magic involved in these things.

Answer (score -1):

```
sum2=0; Correct
sum2.Value=0; Not Correct
```